# parse string to jagged array poppulating dimensions with integers using regex to identify

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, jagged-arrays

I was working with this and came across a new problem as I needed to incorporate a jagged array, so I tried modifying this code like so..

```
string y = "{10} red30, {20} blue12, {30} green90, {40} yellow13 : {15} axe,  
     {25} frog, {33} sandwich, {55} spinach : ...." and so on. 

int[][] Odds = y.Split(':').Select(t => Regex.Matches(t, @"(?<={)\d+(?=})"))  
    .Cast<Match>() .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)) .ToArray();
```

with a new string that had a ":" as a separator between each new array. it gives me the error of "cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int[][]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's beccause the `Matches` method doesn't return a `Match` object, it returns a `MatchCollection` object. You have to get the `Match` objects from each collection and parse the values, then you can turn those into an array:

```
int[][] Odds =
  y.Split(':')
  .Select(t => Regex.Matches(t, @"(?<={)\d+(?=})"))
  .Cast<MatchCollection>()
  .Select(
    m => m.Cast<Match>()
     .Select(n => int.Parse(n.Value))
     .ToArray()
  )
  .ToArray();
```